# How to add margins to a RecyclerView for the last element?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-recyclerview

I several screens that use `RecyclerView` and also has a small `Fragment` that is on top of the `RecyclerView`.  When that `Fragment` is displayed I'd like to make sure I can scroll to the bottom of the `RecyclerView`.  The `Fragment` isn't always displayed.  If I used margins on the `RecyclerView` I'd need to dynamically remove and add them when the `Fragment` is displayed.  I could add margins onto the last item in the list, but that is also complicated and if I load more things later (ie pagination) I'd have to strip off those margins again.

How would I dynamically add or remove margins to the view?  What are some other options to solve this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

So if you want to add some padding at the bottom of your `RecyclerView` you can set the `paddingBottom` and then `clipToPadding` to false. Here's an example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp" />
```

Comment: This was easier to implement and it seemed to work.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 20):

You should use the [Item Decorator](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html).

```
public class MyItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        // only for the last one
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
            outRect.top = /* set your margin here */;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seemed like it would work too and it's a good suggestion.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I use this in kotlin for give margin to last index of `RecyclerView`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), position: Int) {
    if (position == itemsList.lastIndex){
        val params = holder.itemView.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
        params.bottomMargin = 100
        holder.itemView.layoutParams = params
    }else{
        val params = holder.itemView.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        params.bottomMargin = 0
        holder.itemView.layoutParams = params
    }
  //other codes ...
}
```

Comment: @Redesh in my case, it causes java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

[Item decorator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html?hl=es) is the best solution for me

Use this kotlin solution

```
    class RecyclerItemDecoration: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.adapter!!.itemCount - 1) {
            outRect.bottom = 80
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(RecyclerItemDecoration())
```