# Recycler View Scroll to middle of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I am not sure if this would be a duplicate as my wording is probably not the best to describe this on a search. I have a recycler view with a list of strings. Everything works great however, is there a way to make the list scroll a little higher than the bottom of the parent view, in this case keep scrolling up until it hits the middle of the screen? the Recycler view would height is match parent. Thank you in advance!!

Please note: I didnt add code since this is just a regular recycler view nothing special added, let me know if the code is needed as well thank you!

Edit:
this is for a vertical scroll list only. The following images are some list images I got offline but hopefully they can show better what I am trying to accomplish:

I want to be able to scroll the list up to the middle as in the following picture for example:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView horizontal scroll snap in center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134094/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-snap-in-center)

Comment: @AndreClassen thank you for your answer however the article is for a horizontal scrolling. this would be for vertical and is just the scrolling portion.

Comment: @paul590 Did you fix it ?

Comment: @Francky380 yes i did! Thank you my solution was found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011982/how-to-add-margins-to-a-recyclerview-for-the-last-element/37012503